# How would you remove the loop from this matlab code

Tags: matlab, vectorization

Given that we have:

- x is 2d matrix with size [numSamples x numFeatures]
- A is 2d square matrix with size [numFeatures x numFeatures]
- B is a 1d vector with size [1 x numFeatures]

I would like to evaluate the following code without a loop: (or in a way faster way)

```
out = zeros(1,numSamples);
for i = 1:numSamples
    res = sum(repmat(B - x(i,:), numSamples, 1)*A.*(x - repmat(x(i,:), numSamples, 1)), 2).^2;
    out(i) = var(res);
end
```

If you have other suggestions on a faster improvement of the above, it is also more than welcome.

Comment: Let's take a step back.  How fast is this code when you run it on your test data?  Are you not happy with the time?

Comment: Unfortunately no. For a large number of samples it becomes very slow.

Comment: In addition to the comment above, is there a particular formula you try to implement?

Comment: Nothing famous. This is a simplified part of the whole formula, the rest is normalization expressions and I felt that including them will only complicate things. I feel that if you can help me with this simplified expression I am certain that I can extrapolate to the more general expression.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) those *piece-by-piece* for a vectorized solution -

```
P1 = bsxfun(@minus,B,x)*A;
P2 = bsxfun(@minus,x,permute(x,[3 2 1]));
out = var(squeeze(sum(bsxfun(@times,P1,P2),2)).^2.');
```

*Partially vectorized* approach -

```
P = (bsxfun(@minus,B,x)*A).';  %//'
out = zeros(1,numSamples);
for i = 1:numSamples
    out(i) = var((bsxfun(@minus,x,x(i,:))*P(:,i)).^2);
end
```

Comment: thank you for the reply, let me verify that this works :)

Comment: @user2324712 Damn, I see some disbelief there! ;)

Comment: @user2324712 Sure, that's the best way to do it!

Comment: That sure solves it. On my aging laptop, the jit solution in matlab makes the original implementation faster. But I am quite sure that for big data on a gpu your solution takes the cake. Thank you!

Comment: @user2324712 `bsxfun` loves `cake` aka `memory`, so feed it good ;) Just be careful, because with huge data, the memory transfers, rather than the actual computations might slow it down. But, all those would depend a lot on the GPU and the associated hardware.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93621/discussion-between-user2324712-and-divakar).